# sproutcore & rails: where does the sproutcore application live within rails' directory structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sproutcore

I have a working Rails 3 app service plain old HTML CRUD and I want to build a sproutcore client for the same.  I (think) I understand Rails and Sproutcore, but I have an embarrassingly silly newbie question:

*Where do I put the sproutcore app within the rails project structure?*

Specifically, given that I have:

```
myapp/
    app/
    ...
    public/
    ...
```

And I need to say:

```
sc-init SOMETHING
```

What would the SOMETHING be?  (myapp?  public?)
Where does the sproutcore app html come from?
What are the best practices for serving that (routes?)
What really does sc-server do that I can't do with WebBrick/Mongrel, etc.?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't deployed a built SproutCore app yet, so I can't answer where the files should live in the Rails site structure (but I'm guessing within `public/` because you're essentially serving HTML and a lot of Javascript as static assets).

`sc-server` lets you run your application in your localhost while you're developing it, so you don't have to do `sc-build` every time you tweak something with your application. Remember that it's the output of `sc-build` which will be the production site; you won't be serving the site with `sc-server` (nor would you want to).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll need to automate the sc-build step in rake and then make static (globbed?) routes to sc-build's output.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The sproutcore todos tutorial has a section at the end where the plug the app into several "backends" including Rails3.  The Rails3 bit is here:  http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/Todos+06-Building+with+Rails+3

Comment: Alas, the sproutcore tutorial doesn't actually cover where (in rails) to place the client code - it sort of assumes you'll have a different repo for the client (which many will likely do).

Comment: To clarify: I guess this question comes down to how to get sc-build automation when the client code has changed in a rails app.  Sort of like what haml, sass or less do for templates/css compilation.